# Swift Date object with different format

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdate

I've got a `Date` object that holds year/month/day and hour/minute/second data. I need to drop the hour/minute/second part as it's making comparing days problematic.

The issue is that the only obvious way I see of doing it is **turning the day into a `String`** and then using a `DateFormatter` with `yyyy/mm/dd` format to **turn it BACK into a `Date`**. This seems like a waste, is it really the only way?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: A Date object does not hold year/month/day or hour/minute/second data, and a Date has no format. – A Date represents an absolute point in time, stored internally as the number of seconds since 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 2001.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Never convert dates to `String` and back to `Date`.**

You are looking for the `startOfDay` function of `Calendar`:

```
let date = Date()
let startOfDay = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: date)
```